# Writing custom typings for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've added file `custom.d.ts` with following content:

```
declare module 'redis' {
  export interface RedisClient extends NodeJS.EventEmitter {
    setAsync (key: string, value: string): Promise<'OK'>;
    setAsync (key: string, value: string, flag: string): Promise<'OK'>;
    setAsync (key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number): Promise<'OK' | void>;
    setAsync (key: string, value: string, mode: string, duration: number, flag: string): Promise<'OK' | void>;

    getAsync(key: string): Promise<string | null>;
  }
}

declare module 'koa' {
  export interface Request {
    ip: string;
    getCountry(): Promise<string>;
    country?: String;
  }

}
```

Then I run:

```
typings install file:typings/custom.d.ts --save --global
```

But **custom** typings (other typings works good) are still not working:

[image]

I import `typings/index.d.ts` directly from index file. My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES2017",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation:  */
    "allowJs": false,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build/",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "rootDirs": ["./src"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "build",
    "tools"
  ]
}
```

In the start of `src/index.ts` I added:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

Here are `tsc` and `node` versions:

```
Andreys-pc:API andrey$ tsc -v
Version 2.4.1
Andreys-pc:API andrey$ node -v
v8.1.3
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try placing the `custom.d.ts` file in the `typings` folder and changing the `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` line to `/// <reference path="../typings/custom.d.ts" />`

Comment: @guwere this doesn't work because index typings are not imported...

Comment: If you add `/// <reference path="../typings/custom.d.ts" />` as the first line of `index.d.ts` it will cascade and load those custom typings as well.